# JavaFX Bar chart from Map

Tags: java, javafx, charts

I would fill up a Bar chart from a Map.
I'm trying this way, but it does not work:

```
    xAxisAuthor.setLabel(titleX);
    yAxisAuthor.setLabel(titleY);
    ReadJson jsonRead = new ReadJson();
    TypeToken<List<Book>> bookToken = new TypeToken<List<Book>>() {
    };
    Map<String, Long> map = jsonRead.groupJson(new File(UrlAndPath.JSON_LIBRI), bookToken);
    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    series1.setName(title);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : map.entrySet()) {
        String tmpString = entry.getKey();
        Number tmpValue = entry.getValue();
        XYChart.Data<String, Number> d = new XYChart.Data<>(tmpString, tmpValue);
        System.out.println(d);
        series1.getData().add(d);
    }
    barChart.setTitle(title);
    barChart.getData().addAll(series1);
```

In practice you take the key, but not the values.
But it seems to me that XYChart.Data is valued:

```
Data[thomas mann,1,null]
Data[giorgio zarelli,1,null]
```

In the graph the value is always zero.
Can you give me a tip?

Comment: Can you create a [MCVE]? Just write a simple application with a bar chart and a hard-coded map (you don't need the JSON to demonstrate this problem), so that others can run the application and see the problem?

Answer (score 0):

ok, i tried this code without json, and seems to work:

```
    Map<String, Long> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("thomas mann", 1L);
    map.put("clive cussler", 3L);
    map.put("stephen king", 6L);

    XYChart.Series<String, Number> series1 = new XYChart.Series<>();
    series1.setName(title);
    for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : mapOld.entrySet()) {
        String tmpString = entry.getKey();
        Number tmpValue = entry.getValue();
        XYChart.Data<String, Number> d = new XYChart.Data<>(tmpString, tmpValue);
        System.out.println(d);
        series1.getData().add(d);
    }
    barChart.setTitle(title);
    barChart.getData().addAll(series1);
```

maybe the problem is the value long in the json??

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that there were too many values.
This works:

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : map.entrySet()) {
      String tmpString = entry.getKey();
      Long tmpValue = entry.getValue();
      XYChart.Data<String, Number> d = new XYChart.Data<>(tmpString, tmpValue);
      //System.out.println(tmpString + ": " + tmpValue);
      //System.out.println(d);
      series1.getData().add(d);
      count++;
      if (count == 10) {
        break;
      }
  }
```

thanks!!